# Has there been any experiment trying to measure the Ricci Curvature of the universe?

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, curvature

One of the major component of the Einstein equation is the Ricci Curvature. As of now, I understand it mathematically as some sort of trace of the Riemann Tensor, and geometrically as the factor by which volume disort as it travels through space.

My question is, has there been any experiment trying to measure the Ricci curvature in the universe? What did it find the Ricci Curvature function of the universe as?

Comment: Do you mean the Ricci tensor, or the Ricci scalar?

Comment: Ricci Tensor @J.Murray

Comment: I believe it is _mostly_ zero, so you need to measure that ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Answer:**

The Friedmann Equations comes from the EFE (Einstein Field Equations)

$$G_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu \nu}$$
$$R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R= \kappa T_{\mu \nu}$$

Thus, when you measure the dynamics and evolution of the universe, you are kind of measuring the $R_{\mu\nu}$.

**Long Answer:**

As we know, the Ricci Tensor depends on the metric tensor. Considering different metric tensors will lead to different Ricci Tensor. For instance, if consider the FRW metric,

$$g_{\mu\nu}={\rm diag}(1, -\frac{a^2}{1-kr^2}, -a^2r^2, -a^2r^2\sin^2(\theta))$$

the $R_{\mu\nu}$ can be written as,

$$R_{00}  = -3\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}$$
$$R_{ij} = -[\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}+2(\frac{\dot{a}}{a})^2+2\frac{k}{a^2}]g_{ij}$$

We also know that, $$\frac{\dot{a}}{a} = H,~~\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = -qH^2$$

By using these expressions, we can write $R_{\mu\nu}$ as

$$R_{00} = 3qH^2$$
$$R_{ij} = [qH^2 - 2H^2 - 2\frac{k}{a^2}]g_{ij}$$

From these cosmological parameters you can obtain some of the information about the Ricci Tensor. But in a sense measuring the Ricci Tensor is kind of measuring the dynamics of the universe since they make up the $G_{\mu\nu}$, which determines the dynamics of the universe.

Comment: Hmm so is there a non zero Ricci going on or not o_o

Comment: I have written the ricci tensor for spacetime...you can also write it for only space. Well they are non-zero, they should be non-zero due to fact that the universe is expanding...You can measure the spatial curvature of the universe ($k$) but thats the curvature of the **space, not spacetime**.

Comment: I never heard an experiment that can measure the spacetime curvature...people are of course trying to measure the spatial curvature of the universe. My point is that measuring $R_{\mu\nu}$ is kind of meausring the dynamics of the universe...

Comment: @seVenVo1d I would say measuring the Hubble parameter (and derivatives like the acceleration parameter $q$) *is* a measurement of the spacetime curvature, precisely based on the calculation in your answer (in other words, given $H$ you can calculate $R_{\mu\nu}$).

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I agree with you. The information in $R_{\mu\nu}$ is coming from $g_{\mu \nu}$, which contains the scale factor..At least that's my interpretation.