# Has the curvature of space from GR ever been validated?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, experimental-physics, astronomy, curvature

It is my understanding that at low gravitational potentials like we experience on earth that the time curvature dominates and that the curvature of space only becomes relevant within stronger gravitational potentials.

I know GR has been validated to great precision around earth and the sun.  Do these validations of GR include the influence of the curvature of space or are they only validating the curvature of time since it is dominate?

Comment: The experiment during 1915 solar eclipse , validated the curvature of space as well where the light from those stars are unusual from behind as its position appears to be changed from its original position

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709215/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356166/2451 and links therein.